# Using ajax.php for video presentation in kaltura

Tags: php, ajax

I am writing codes for video presentation. But facing problem in using ajax.php. I found these codes inside http://www.kaltura.com/projects/VideoPresentationDemo/
 ,

but I don't know how to call ajax.php , anybody can help me?

```
function entries_added(entries)
{
   $("#doc_uploading").html('Processing '+kuploader_selected_filename);
   entry = entries[0];
   set_document_entry_id(entry.entryId);
   // entry id = entry.entryId
   // request conversion using ajax
   $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php?action=convert&entryId='+entry.entryId,
      type: 'get',
      success: function(download_url){
         set_converted_doc_swf_url(download_url);
         var timeoutId = setTimeout('updateDocConversionStatus()',10000);
         set_docConvertCheckerId(timeoutId);
      }
   });
}
```

Please help me to download ajax.php.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may not have jQuery loaded; the `$.ajax({ url: 'ajax.php' })` should be working to "download" ajax.php already.

On the Video Presentation Demo page you link to, you can enter this code into your browser's console; you should see an XMLHTTPRequest object printed, followed by 'success' if it works.

```
$.ajax({ url:'ajax.php', success: function(url) { console.log('success'); } });
```

On your own site, do you have an `ajax.php` handler to make requests to?